# I want to crop an image, draw a smaller size image without caching the images.... What is the best way or good code to get this done in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am storing the images in database. I get the NSData and create an image from it. Now I want to crop or draw a smaller image of the existing image in database which I am getting from the query. I don't want to cache the images since I am using them in bulk and want to release them as soon as the view being displayed where the images are used is popped up.

Is there any efficient solution to make sure that images don't consume memory at the background once their use is over...

I will appreciate the lines of code for this.

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[There was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more) an excellent post on this topic.